# apt-get is stuck with mysql after creating a vm from snapshot in Google cloud

Tags: mysql, virtual-machines, apt, snapshot, gcloud

I'm using Google cloud and I have a vm (Ubuntu 18.04) that is working fine. The apt-get command works totally fine and mysql service is running well. Let's call it vm-1

I needed to create another a duplicate vm, so I first made a snapshot of vm-1, and used this snapshot to created a new vm, called vm-2.

As I work on vm-2, I found that the simply command of `sudo apt-get install ***` would fail and get stuck at a step related to mysql-server. Below is an example:

```
John@vm-2:~$ sudo apt-get install tree
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
tree is already the newest version (1.7.0-5).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libnvidia-common-390 linux-gcp-headers-5.0.0-1033
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 170 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.30-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1: 14143
ERROR: Database files are locked. Daemon already running?
Warning: Unable to start the server. Please restart MySQL and run mysql_upgrade to ensure the database is ready for use.
/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1: 14143
ERROR: Database files are locked. Daemon already running?
Warning: Unable to start the server.
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-08-12 18:11:39 JST; 7ms ago
  Process: 24068 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 24046 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1711 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
John@vm-2:~$
```

It keeps saying that

```
ERROR: Database files are locked. Daemon already running?
Warning: Unable to start the server. Please restart MySQL and run mysql_upgrade to ensure the database is ready for use.
/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1: 14143
ERROR: Database files are locked. Daemon already running?
Warning: Unable to start the server.
```

How is apt-get related to mysql-server in the first place?? I have always thought that they are 2 independent softwares.

How can I fix this issue? I have done nothing but restoring a snapshot that works totally fine in the original vm. With everything being the same, how come `apt-get` would fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following log line :
`2 not fully installed or removed.` suggests that apt-get is trying to complete an earlier failed package installation (mysql-server-5.7) before proceeding with the new installation request (tree), which is why you see mysql-server mentioned in that output.

I would suggest identifying if mysql server is already running via `ps -ef | grep -i mysql` or `netstat -lntp | grep 3306` and resolving the issue causing `ERROR: Database files are locked. Daemon already running?`

one this is resolved, it will allow the previous package installation to complete successfully

1. If you started mysql yourself manually, then I would suggest stopping that process, and running the original command again.
2. If it's possible that if you started mysql at some point previously as `root`, you might want to check the permissions on the files in the `/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1` folder

Comment: awesome! I did `sudo kill` on whatever processes that showed up on `ps -ef | grep -i mysql` and then purged and reinstalled mysql.